# How do I match on the property of a relationship in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to return a relationship based on the content of one of it's properties.

The data is organised like this;

```
(l:LEFT)-[h:HAS]->(r:RIGHT)
```

The `HAS` relationship contains a string property `prop`.

I've tried the following;

```
match (l:LEFT)-[h:HAS]->(r:RIGHT)
where h.prop = "MyProp"
return l, h, r;
```

and

```
match (l:LEFT)-[h:HAS {prop:"MyProp"}]->(r:RIGHT)
return l, h, r;
```

but both return no rows.

This question - [Neo4j Match Node Property OR Relationship Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949573/neo4j-match-node-property-or-relationship-property) seem to show that I'm doing it correctly, but either it does not work, or I made some mistake (most likely).

I'm using Neo4j v2.3.2.

Comment: Is the property name "prop" or "PROP"? Property names are case sensitive.

Comment: They are the same case - I'll correct the example to reflect this.

Comment: What does this query return?: `MATCH (l:LEFT)-[h:HAS]->(r:RIGHT) RETURN h LIMIT 1;`

Comment: In the Graph view it returns a LEFT and a RIGHT with two HAS between them.
In the Row view it returns a HAS relationship.

Comment: Please show the `HAS` relationship.

Comment: It worked. Since these nodes and relationship are examples made from my real code, I was surprised that it did. I looked more closely at the difference, and the problem (I'm sorry to say) was that the property gets created from a CSV file where the "prop" values are like this; "MyProp1, MyProp2, MyProp3" and not like this; "MyProp1,MyProp2,MyProp3" (space after the comma). That was the reason the match didn't work - when I included the space it worked.
This is my first question here, what should I do with this question, delete it? Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: I think you can delete it, as it would probably not help anyone else.

Comment: Instead of deleting the question you can answer it and accept your own answer. That whitespace is not trimmed when importing from CSV is something that others get tripped up on—if you explain that this is what happened others may find your answer and be helped.

Comment: Thanks - I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was unrelated to the query.

The problem was (I'm sorry to say) that the property gets created from a CSV file where the "prop" values are like this; "MyProp1, MyProp2, MyProp3" and not like this; "MyProp1,MyProp2,MyProp3" (space after the comma). That was the reason the match didn't work - when I included the space it worked.